# Why do i need to select the elements from the list in order to store it to the database

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, struts2

There are two lists with add and remove button as shown below.

[image]

I need to save all the values from the right side list(selected cities) to the database. But its not working properly.
Why do i need to select all the options(new delhi, sydney) in order to get them stored in the database. It should go to database by only putting them to right table and hitting save. The bean property is marked as String. Is the problem occurring because it is String? Should it be String[ ]? Here's the code.

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <div style="text-align:center;font-weight:bold;"></div> 
        <form:select id="unselected" path="totalCities" multiple="true" size="10" cssStyle="width:100%" ondblclick="javascript:swap('unselected', 'selected');">
        <form:options items="${refTotalCities}" itemLabel="desc" itemValue="code"/>
        </form:select>
    </td>
    <td class="center">
    <br/><br/><br/><br/>
    <input type="button" name="<fmt:message key="button.add"/>" value="<fmt:message key="button.add"/>" onclick="javascript:swap('unselected', 'selected');"/><br/>
    <input type="button" name="<fmt:message key="button.remove"/>" value="<fmt:message key="button.remove"/>" onclick="javascript:swap('selected', 'unselected');"/>
    </td>
    <td class="data center">
    <div style="text-align:center;font-weight:bold;"></div>
    <form:select id="selected" path="selectedCities" multiple="true" size="10" cssStyle="width:100%" ondblclick="javascript:swap('selected', 'unselected');">
    <form:options items="${selectedCities}" itemLabel="desc" itemValue="code"/>
    </form:select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Because only selected values will be submitted.

Comment: that 'selected' thing is the id, i don't think that has to do anything with it.

Comment: For hitting save the submit button is required or you doing it on the fly?

Comment: Your update code would be more relevant here than the form. Although I do notice the 'save' button you refer to doesn't exist on the form.